# Windows SBS 2003 SP2 freezing after installing Trend Micro WFBS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-sbs-2003, anti-virus

I'm new in charge of a server running Windows SBS 2003 with SP 2.
First thing after I got in charge of the system was to update the old WFBS 3.7 to the current version.
Now the users reporting that sometimes the network connection to the server is lost and the whole PC freezes up.
I found the following in the event log:

```
Source: Service Control Manager
Event ID: 7011
Description: Timeout (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for a transaction response from the NtFrs service.
```

After some searching I found the recommendation to turn of smart scan for the clients in WFBS.
But this was not the solution for the problem.

One other thing what I found is to increase the LAN Autodisconnect parameter as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;138365)

But I'm not sure of the implications and negative effects of increase this parameter.

Dose someone have any experience with altering this parameter. Any other recommendations?

Comment: So I updated the parameter now to the maximum value (0xffff). On Monday I will get feedback from the customer if it fixed the problem

Comment: The above mentioned error still occurs. It is still strange to see the 30000 ms even though I have adjusted the parameters in the Regestry.

Comment: Have you verified that the list of excluded file types and folders are in effect?

Comment: @GregAskew Thank you for your comment. Yes I have excluded all Files and Directory's as recommended by [Trend Micro Knowledge Base](http://esupport.trendmicro.com/solution/en-us/1059795.aspx).
Any other ideas?